# Enable autocomplete for standalone ruby files in NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: ruby, netbeans, ide, netbeans-6.9

I'm having problems with ruby autocomplete in NetBeans.

Autocomplete works perfectly fine when I'm in a NetBeans Ruby Project. But when I use netbeans to open a standalone file. The autocomplete don't work anymore.

Is there a way to enable autocomplete for standalone ruby files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable code completion for standalone ruby files in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476168/how-to-enable-code-completion-for-standalone-ruby-files-in-netbeans)